# Dygraph code crashes on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dygraphs

My dygraph code does not work on IE8. The Console shows this error:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'CanvasRenderingContext2D' is undefined 
dygraph-combined.js, line 2 character 13300
```

This is the line that crashes in "dygraph-combined.js":

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.installPattern=function(e){if ...
```

The graph is correctly displayed on IE9 and IE7, using the exact same code.

None of the possible solutions that I have researched have worked yet (many of them being just "include excanvas.js").

**Edit1:** after David Kiger's feedback, I have tried formatting the header exactly as required, but it still does not work. I have also removed Yii's bootstrap to isolate the problem. This is the exact code:

```
<!-- DOCTYPE html -->
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9;" http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/js/dygraph/excanvas.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/fonto/js/dygraph/dygraph-combined.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

Commenting this line in excanvas.js did not work either:

```
//el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

**Edit2:** SOLVED!

So I had to combine both solutions:

Format code for IE...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9;">
```

...AND commenting the line in excanvas.js

```
//el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

The order is also very important:

- First excanvas.js
- Then dygraph-combined.js

Thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: Did you read the all of the details at http://dygraphs.com/#ie? It's more than just including excanvas for IE8. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/dygraphs-users/xgcJ4EvH_l8.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a very instructive post from Dan. Nevertheless I have tried 2 of these 3 solutions and I still could not make the code work. And the 3rd one (changing to FlashCanvas) does not seem like a good idea after reading the feedback comments.